# Grant access to file in S3 bucket by a unique hash (Go)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have an S3 bucket. I want to grant access to a single file within that bucket to a unique person. Is it possible to grant access based on a secure hash or something like that?

So for instance. File is uploaded to bucket. Emails is sent to user with a link:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycoolbucket/test.txt?key=asdqwerwerhsdhsdfh23562346

Access to that file is granted if the key (or whatever) is present and correct. If that key wasn't correct access would be denied. And access would only be granted for that single file in the bucket. Trying to avoid changing policies and what not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the risk of stating the extremely obvious, see Example 3 here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking over all the existing golang packages and what not I decided it was best to just build my own package specifically for creating a secure url to a specific item in an S3 bucket. It works great but documentation is a work in progress. Hopefully it helps someone:

https://github.com/markhayden/s3querybuilder

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at pre-signed URLs, for example in Java: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html